# Flutter Calculating the total price of the items in thier category

Tags: list, android-studio, flutter, dart

To-Do App

```
class ToDoItem{
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final Color color;
  final int price;
  final IconData icon;
  final String todoListId;

  const ToDoItem({
    @required this.color,
    @required this.id,
    @required this.todoListId,
    @required this.price,
    @required this.title,
    @required this.icon,
  });}
```

I am struggling to add up the total sum  of items price in the to-Do lists that is equal to todoListId
for example :

THE LISTS SCREEN

[image]

THE LISTS ITEMS SCREEN

[image]

so I am trying to calculate the  Total Items Price

this is what I have tried:

```
  List<Map<String, Object>> get totalItemsPrice{
    return List.generate(1, (index) {
      var totalPriceSum = 0.0;
      for (var i = 0; i < toDo.length; i++) {
        totalPriceSum = toDo[index].amount + totalPriceSum ;
      }
      return {
        'price': totalSum,
      };
    }).toList();
  }

  double get totalPriceSum {
    return totalItemsPrice.fold(0.0, (sum, item) {
      return sum + item['price'];
    });
  }
```

the toDo looks like this:

```
List<ToDO> toDo= [];
```

But it is not working it is calculating the total price of all of the to-do items when I want it to only calculate the total price of the items that are in their category

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to filter based on the item's `todoListId` then you will need to provide it to the method. From there, use a `where` before the `fold` to only sum items with the matching id:

```dart
double totalPriceSum(int todoListId) {
  return ItemsPrice.where((item) => item.todoListId == todoListId)
                   .fold(0.0, (sum, item) => sum + item['price']); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's see below code

```
double totalPriceSum() {
 return ItemsPrice.map((item) => item.price * item.quantity)
               .reduce((ele1, ele2) => ele1 + ele2); 
}
```

Comment: Please read "[answer]". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.